# Firebase Emulator with Jest Test cases in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, jestjs, firebase-tools

I'm trying to get data from Emulator store but I haven't the idea of how can I achieve it. still, I tried to implement it but got the below error. my main focus is HOW CAN I USE THE Emulator in the Jest Test CASES. I'm writing it. I have already setup the emulator which is working fine. can you please guide me...

[image]

user.test.js file

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase-admin';
import { collection, doc } from 'firebase/firestore';

import { initializeTestApp, loadFirestoreRules } from '@firebase/rules-unit-testing';
import { setUserData, companyRef, stored, company, product } from '../mock';import userSlice, {
  hasError,
  initialState,
  resetStateData,
  setUser,
} from '../src/redux/slices/user';

beforeAll(async () => {
  await loadFirestoreRules({ projectId, rules: '../firestore.rules' });
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await app.delete();
});

const mockStore = configureMockStore();

const store = mockStore(stored);

describe('User test case :-', () => {
  const error = { status: '401', message: 'Something went to wrong' };
  const userId = 'VOmxX13c7ygUhOmzXZefXfnLLwZ2';
  const otherUserData = setUserData;
  const companyRefMock = companyRef;
  const dispatch = jest.fn();

  beforeEach(async () => {
    // Set up necessary data before each test
    // You can create documents in the Firestore emulator using 'setDoc'
    await setDoc(doc(collection(db, 'users'), '5e86809283e28b96d2d38537'), {
      /* user data */
    });
    await setDoc(doc(collection(db, 'super-user'), '5e86809283e28b96d2d38537'), {
      /* super user data */
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  // Test of Success for updateUser
  test('setUser action should set user profile data correctly', async () => {
    const snapshot = await firestore.collection('your_collection').get();

    // const snapshot = await jest.mock(firestore.collection('user').get());
    console.log('snapshot', snapshot);
    await dispatch(setUser(userId, otherUserData));
    // check loading state
    expect(dispatch).toBeCalled(dispatch(userLoading()));
    // check setAuthentication state
    expect(dispatch).toBeCalled(dispatch(setAuthentication(true)));
    expect(dispatch).toBeCalled(dispatch(hasError(error)));

    // Compare with the store
    expect(store.getState().isUserLoading).toBe(false);
    expect(store.getState().isAuthenticated).toBe(true);
    expect(store.getState().error).toEqual(error);
  });
});
```

user.js [Redux action]

```
export function setUser(userId, otherUserData) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(slice.actions.userLoading(true));
    try {
      const userRef = doc(DB, 'users', userId);
      const userDocumentSnap = await getDoc(userRef);
      const docSuperUserRef = await doc(collection(DB, 'super-user'), userId);
      const docSuperUserSnapshot = await getDoc(docSuperUserRef);
      const isSuperUser = docSuperUserSnapshot.exists();
      let userProfile = userDocumentSnap.data();
      if (otherUserData) {
        userProfile = { ...otherUserData, ...userProfile, isSuperUser };
      }
      if (isSuperUser) {
        dispatch(getAllCompanies());
      }
      dispatch(slice.actions.setUserSuccess({ userProfile, userRef }));
      dispatch(setUserInvitations(userProfile));
      dispatch(setAllProducts());

      if (userProfile.companies) {
        dispatch(slice.actions.setCompanies(userProfile.companies));
      }
      dispatch(slice.actions.setAuthentication(true));
    } catch (error) {
// console.error(error);

      dispatch(slice.actions.hasError(error));
      dispatch(slice.actions.setAuthentication(false));
    } finally {
      dispatch(slice.actions.userLoading(false));
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The piece you're missing is to connect the SDK to the emulator like so:

```
connectFirestoreEmulator(db, '127.0.0.1', 8080);
```

Which will direct all requests to the emulator and not your production App.

---

Alternatively, since you're using the `rules-unit-testing` library you can accomplish the same with the following:

```
let testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
  projectId: "demo-project-1234",
  firestore: {
    rules: fs.readFileSync("firestore.rules", "utf8"),
  },
});

const alice = testEnv.authenticatedContext("alice", { … });
// Use the Firestore instance associated with this context
await assertSucceeds(setDoc(alice.firestore(), '/users/alice'), { ... });
```

The latter is described in https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests

**Edit:** The { ... } part in the authenticatedContext call is an **optional** [TokenOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/emulator-suite/rules-unit-testing/rules-unit-testing.md#tokenoptions) object.

See this testing [example taken from the quickstart tests](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-testing/blob/8c0b7db5616e09824a6f44415e4128d2d8dd4fa2/unit-test-security-rules-v9/test/database.spec.js#L86) for usage without the TokenOptions.

```js
testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
    database: {rules: readFileSync('database.rules.json', 'utf8')},
  });
...
const aliceDb = testEnv.authenticatedContext('alice').database();
const unauthedDb = testEnv.unauthenticatedContext().database();

await assertSucceeds(update(ref(aliceDb, 'users/alice'), { favorite_color: "blue" }));
await assertFails(update(ref(aliceDb, 'users/bob'), { favorite_color: "red" }));
```

Comment: what do i need to pass in the second argument in the testEnv.authenticatedContext("alice", { … });.
can you please tell me?

Comment: The comment section was too small so I added it in the answer in the `Edit` section. You don't need to specify this part if you don't want to.